Google Location service to fetch multiple categories POI (point of interest) API
Is there an API available in google location services that supports fetching Points of Interest (POI) information across multiple categories, such as hotels, schools, and rail tracks, within a single API call?
expecting the single API which will return poi based on the latlng with within some radius
